# How To select image data type with 'like' in mssqlserver

Tags: sql-server, getimagedata

I have one table that has Image Data type column, that column contains `Pdf` and `txt` file.

My question is how to search any  word with "LIKE" 
in Sql 
Exemple

```
Select * from tablename where ImageColumn LIKE @searchingword
```

Comment: How would you search for "stack" in the stack overflow logo image?

Comment: For searching PDFs look at full text search. You will need to download the Adobe IFilter. @lc. `image` is a (deprecated) binary data type in SQL Server and does not necessarily refer to actual images. `varbinary(max)` is the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, not sure how it will react to PDF file though...

```
select *
from dbo.tablename
where convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max), ImageColumn)) LIKE @searchingword
```

Comment: It is not possibe because                                       **Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed.**

Comment: @ÖzcanGöbekli - crap.. I knew that..  Updating answer.

Comment: @ÖzcanGöbekli - true, converting binary to varchar will be slow.  FullTextSearch is definately the way to go, especially if there's a plugin for PDF files.  Also, if you change the datatype to `varbinary(max)`, that's one less conversion.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
from dbo.tablename
where convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max), ImageColumn)) LIKE '%' + 
CHAR(0x00)+ CHAR(0x01)+ CHAR(0x02) +'%'**
```